# Proof-verification: Every convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

I know the correct proof in which path-connectedness of the convex set $S$ is shown. Here I show my work:

> Let $f: S \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ be a 2-valued function. Assume $f$ is not constant, say, there exist $x, y \in S$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=1$. Then for all $0 < \theta < 1$, $(1- \theta)y + \theta x \in S, f((1- \theta)y + \theta x) = (1- \theta)(1)+\theta(0)$ which does not equal to $0$ or $1$. Contradiction.

Does the last equality holds? I am confused. The metric space I am considering is $\mathbb{R}^n$. Can I 'pull out' the constant in calculating the function?

If not, can I amend my proof to make it valid? Or path-connectedness is the only way out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality doesn't hold generally as $f$ doesn't have to be linear. Rather, you should observe that the composition $θ \mapsto f((1 - θ)y + θx)$ is continuous and onto $\{0, 1\}$, which contradicts the connectedness of $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Thanks for replying. In fact, in a general metric space, can I argue in the same way that every convex set is connected?

Comment: @LeeKM How would you define a convex set in a general metric space?

Comment: You are right! Sorry about that!